# Rosserial stm32f4 unable to connect device

Tags: ros, rosserial, rosserial-python

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am currently working to integrate an STM32F4 Discovery board with an IMU for use with ROS using rosserial_python. When trying to retrieve data from the STM32F4's on-board accelerometer (LIS3021 I believe) for testing, I encounter the following error:

Error: unable to connect with device; possible link problem or link software version mismatch such as hydro rosserial_python and groovy Arduino.

I am using the following command:
rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py _port:=/dev/ttyUSB0 _baud:=9600

I have checked my baud rate and serial ports and verified they are correct. Even so, I ran the command with the most common baud rates from 1200 - 115200 with no success. My udev rules are correct and up-to-date for the USB-UART bride I am using with the STM32F4. I encounter this error with the board regardless of which program I have flashed to the board (hello world, blinky, accelerometer data retrieval). I have looked at nearly all the solutions posted for this problem and implemented them to no success (they are almost all for Arduino unfortunately). I am not sure what further steps to take to address this issue and would greatly appreciate any input.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/264709/rosserial-stm32f4-unable-to-connect-device/) by [tchuss](https://answers.ros.org/users/30905/tchuss/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-06-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Because the **STM32F4** is not officially supported by **rosserial**, can you post your `*Hardware.h` file and explain how did you add rosserrial support for your board.

---

Originally posted by [rreignier](https://answers.ros.org/users/21983/rreignier/) with karma: 544 on 2017-09-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0